# Difficulty to prove a result from "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning"

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, machine-learning

I am studying classification with the book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" written by C. Bishop.

I tried to demonstrate a result of the book but I did not find the same result as the one in the book.

Given that $$ a_k = \ln{p(x|C_k)p(C_k)}$$ and
$$ p(x|C_k) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{D/2}} \frac{1}{|\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp \Bigg (-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_k)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_k) \Bigg )$$

I would like to show that $$a_k = w_k^T x+ \omega_{k0} $$

with $$ w_k = \Sigma^{-1} \mu_k$$
and $$ \omega_{k0} = -\frac{1}{2} \mu_k^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_k + \ln p(C_k)$$
I also precise that $x$ and $\mu_k$ are D-dimensional vectors and $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix.

These equations can be found pages 198 and 199, (Eq 4.63) and (Eq 6.68).

Here what I found
$$a_k = \mu_k^T \Sigma^{-1} x -\frac{1}{2} \mu_k^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu_k + \ln p(C_k) -\frac{1}{2} x^T \Sigma^{-1} x -\frac{2}{D} \ln(2 \pi) -\frac{1}{2} \ln|\Sigma|$$

You can see that I have three additional terms, do you know how I can eliminate these terms?

Comment: You may want to define your notation. Okay, $p(x\mid C_k)$ is the density of $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma)$ with $X\in \mathbb R^d$. But the rest is?

Comment: $C$ is a discrete random variable that can take $K$ values, $C_k$ is one of them. $p(C_k)$ denotes the probability that $C$ takes the value $C_k$. $\mu_k$ denotes the mean of the Gaussian and $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix, the determinant is $ |\Sigma | $. $D$ is the dimension of the random vector.

Comment: The book explains: "We see that the quadratic terms in x from the exponents of the Gaussian densities
have cancelled (due to the assumption of common covariance matrices) leading to
a linear function of x in the argument of the logistic sigmoid"

Comment: I read this but it was not very helpful. In fact it is not well explained in the book. We should not use the formula given for $a_k$: $$a_k = p(x | C_k)p(C_k)$$
But instead compute directly $p(C_k | x)$, write it as a softmax application and finally identify what are in the exponentials. And then we find the same result.